# Save and restore selection in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

Can anybody tell my how to keep selection in [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)?

I have a list of objects in my control which I receive from a database. User selects one and then hits "Refresh" (so that all items are retrieved from the database again). Selection is "jumping", but I want it to keep on a user selected object.

I must compare objects by their unique id, so that sorting or new objects from the database must not impact on user selection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "Refresh" calling `olv.SetObjects()`?

Comment: Yes, it does. It receives new objects from a database, so it must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

Once you clear objects and build the list again selected items disappear regardless of you are keeping it in a variable or not. Because to keep this info the variable for selected items must be declared as a variable which is dynamically attached to OLV control. That's why once the list is cleared the variable won't be able to keep selected items.

**About workaround:**

I have a workaround for this issue. Most of people may think to implement `objectListViewUserList.SelectedItem` property but this property has some issues. It is not consistent with some reason. So for my workaround, I will introduce this property `objectListViewUserList.MouseMoveHitTest`. It sounds like it's a test variable but it works like a charm.

**Assumption:**

Additionally, to implement this workaround, it is assumed that first column is the ID column.

**Workaround:**

Here's the workaround. Keep the text information of the first column in a public string in the click event.

```
    private void objectListViewUserList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (objectListViewUserList.MouseMoveHitTest.Item != null)
            selectedItemText = objectListViewUserList.MouseMoveHitTest.Item.Text;
        else
            selectedItemText = "";
    }
```

In my application, I refresh the OLV control with `fillOnlineUsers` method. This is arbitrary. It can be any method. In my application this method works with a timer. After each refresh, I select the items by searching the ID in the new list.

```
    public void fillOnlineUsers()
    {
        objectListViewUserList.ClearObjects();
        objectListViewUserList.AddObjects(onlineUsers);
        objectListViewUserList.BuildList();
        if (selectedItemText != "")
        {
            foreach (OLVListItem olvi in objectListViewUserList.Items)
                if (olvi.Text == selectedItemText)
                    olvi.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

This workaround has O(n) complexity. Which means it may slow down your application if you have thousands of records.

Comment: You can avoid the O(n) by implementing `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on your data class and setting SelectedObjects (see my answer).  Also means you can use Intersect and Union etc with old and new instances.  But no luck if you don't have control of the data class.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution (based on Barry Guvenkaya answer). I assume that

1. More than one item can be selected (by mouse or by keyboard)
2. Object ID is not stored in a column of OLVListItem, but inside the object (columns can be hidden, their order can be different).

My `Refresh()` function:

```
PushSelected();
objectListView.SetObjects(...);
PopSelected();
```

Save and restore selection with:

```
private List<Guid> selected;   // Keeping the ID's of selected objects

public void PushSelected()
{
    // Value of SelectedList can be get using
    // objectListView.SelectedObjects

    selected.Clear();
    foreach (MyObject r in SelectedList)  
        selected.Add(r.id);
}

public void PopSelected()
{
    D.DeselectAll();

    if (selected.Count != 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < objectListView.Items.Count; i ++)
        {
            OLVListItem item = (OLVListItem)objectListView.Items[i];
            Guid g = ((MyObject)item.RowObject).id;
            if (selected.Contains(g))
                item.Selected = true;
        }
 }
```

Of course, this solution also has O(n) complexity and even O(n*n) if all items were selected.

Comment: Thanks for contributing my solution peschanko. I'm glad that I could be of assistance. Yours also looks promising and gives the ability to select multiple rows. Can you please give an up for my solution? Cheers.

Comment: Of course I was trying to give an up for your solution, but do not have enough of reputation, sorry :(

Comment: Hope my ups would help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

if you use version 2.9.1 of the ObjectListView and just use olv.SetObjects(YourDataObject)
the existing selection will be preserved and you do not need any of the time consuming methods or workarounds to remember the active selection.

Your code should try to maintain the original objects in the Data if possible, update those where needed. If you clear all objects and recreate new ones, you loose the selection and are forced to resort to other ways to remember selection.

Answer (score 0):

so from the other posts it looks like your records have a Guid, that's good news! If you implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` then you can clear the list and reselect the old selection by passing in the old list `olv.SelectedObjects.Cast<object>().ToList()`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Guid _guid1;
    private Guid _guid2;

    class MyClass
    {
        public readonly Guid Guid;
        public string Key;
        public string Value;


        public MyClass(Guid guid, string key, string value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Guid = guid;
            Value = value;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Guid.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is MyClass)
                return this.Guid.Equals(((MyClass) obj).Guid);

            return base.Equals(obj);
        }
    }



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        olv.FullRowSelect = true;
        olv.HideSelection = false;

        _guid1 = Guid.Parse("026c90aa-7fb8-452d-b8bc-b42fd7bc0e7f");
        _guid2 = Guid.Parse("85ea0ce0-da65-412f-8198-724c196342da");

        olv.AddObjects(new []
        {
            //two objects that will be updated
            new MyClass(_guid1,"go","nuts"), 
            new MyClass(_guid2,"lol","rly?"),

            //one object that will disapear
            new MyClass(Guid.NewGuid(),"bye","bye")
        });

    }

    private void BtnRefreshObjects_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        olv.BeginUpdate();

        //remember the old objects
        var oldSelection = olv.SelectedObjects.Cast<object>().ToList();

        //swap them for the new objects
        olv.ClearObjects();
        olv.AddObjects(
            new []
        {
            //This object stays the same
            new MyClass(_guid1,"go","nuts"), 
            //This object changes fields (but is still the same record due to Guid)
            new MyClass(_guid2,"omg2","omg3"),
            //This is a new object
            new MyClass(Guid.NewGuid(),"omg5","omg6")
        });

        //reset the old selection (even though they are stale objects the selection works because of Equality override)
        olv.SelectedObjects = oldSelection;
        olv.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```